# Is there a global: false for .load(url) functions?

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc-4

I have a loader which is called on all ajaxStart and ajaxStop functions.

```
$(document).on({
    ajaxStart: function () { $body.addClass("loading"); },
    ajaxStop: function () { $body.removeClass("loading"); }
});
```

The loader displays for $.ajax functions, which is correct.
But the loader also displays for

```
$("#div").load('www.mydummyurl.com')
```

Is there a way i can unbind the ajaxStart event for .load()?
or a

```
$("#div").load('www.mydummyurl.com', global:false)
```

I am lost! Please help.

Comment: `load` is just a wrapper for `$.ajax` so it is an ajax call. So there is no real difference between these two methods

Comment: Not really, as `load()` makes an AJAX request

Comment: Really for me this seems like an XY problem. Why do you need these `ajaxStart` and stop methods? What your doing seems very heavy handed.

Comment: @Liam Seems like they're displaying a loading gif/bar/something when an ajax call is being made

Comment: @Liam agree it appears to be an XY problem, but to me the question would be why would you *not* want to show a loading state in some cases but do in others.

Comment: To address the question: a quick look at the jquery (3.1.1) source shows that there is no way to add additional arguments to the wrapped `$.ajax` call.  So unwrap (as per hsz's answer) it or re-wrap it with a new load plugin.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of using `.load` shorthand, use `.ajax`:

```
$.ajax({
  url: "www.mydummyurl.com",
  global: false,
});
```

It will allow you to pass extra parameters - like `global` in this case.

Ref: https://api.jquery.com/Ajax_Events/ (Global Events section)

Comment: Here you won't load any content in any targeted DOM element. And btw, loaded content can contains other script to handle. Would need to check jQuery source code to see how exactly to handle it, and finally, that's not that simple imho. EDIT: just checking source code, $.fn.load method exclude explecitely script tags, so at least this should be easier than expected to deal with

Comment: finally after breaking my head for a day! this works. thank you!

Answer (score 2):

You need to set up inside ajaxSetup like so :

```
$.ajaxSetup({
  global : false,
  .....
});
```